# UITableView with Custom Cell in Edit Mode not pushing cell over

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell that has two labels. They are both using auto layout and are anchored inside the cell.

When entering into edit mode the labels are not pushed over to the right like the default controls.

I have set the default `textLabel`'s text to test this.

What do I need to change to move over the custom labels as well?

[image]

Comment: This looks like your custom labels are attached to the cell directly. Make sure they're children of the cell's `contentView`.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks @Gereon!

Answer (score 0):

You should use cell's `contentView` for UI elements.